# delete a photo tag in rtmedia

Tags: buddypress, media-library

I am using rtmedia photo tag in my website. When deleting a user I am also trying to delete all the photo tags added by him on the albums of other users. How can I do that?. Is there any functions available or should I write a custom one for that?

Answer (score 3):

It is fixed in v2.2.4. I suggest you to update your plugin.

Or you can do it by adding following condition in tag rendering foreach loop `RTMediaPhotoTag.php > function tag(){...}`

```
if(get_user_by('id', $tagged) === false ){
      $this-> delete_tag($tagged,$media_id);
      continue ;
}
```

You should post this issue on [rtmedia support forum](https://rtcamp.com/support/forum/rtmedia/)